# how can i update chrome.devtools.panels when watching?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want refresh information in custom panel.

but onShown could not refresh when watching panel. how can i or... must use setInterval() in onShow?

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html"
}
```

devtools.html:

```
<html><body><script src="devtools.js"></script></body></html>
```

devtools.js:

```
var view_counts = 0;
chrome.devtools.panels.create(
  "sample", "sample.png", "sample.html",
  function(panel){
    panel.onShown.addListener(function(panel_window){
      panel_window.document.getElementById("show_count").innerHTML = view_counts;
      // and moer update.
    });
  }
);
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(
  function(entries) {
    if(entries.request.url == "http://example.com/"){
      view_counts++;
      // and more analytics
    }
  }
);
```

sample.html:

```
<html><body>count: <div id="show_count">-</div></body></html>
```

Comment: Save panel_window in a global variable. Modify its DOM in the onRequestFinished listener.

Answer (score 2):

When you refresh the page your custom panel doesn't refresh itself. Also panel's `onShown` event is fired when the custom panel is visible/clicked. Thus, your code won't able to show the refresh information.

You have to store the `panel_window` reference in global variable so that you can access the same in `onRequestFinished` event handler to do the needful. I have edited your code, please check it below:

Please change your devtools.js as follows

```
var view_counts = 0;
var _windowObj;

chrome.devtools.panels.create(
  "sample", "sample.png", "sample.html",
  function(panel){
    panel.onShown.addListener(function tmp(panel_window){
      panel.onShown.removeListener(tmp);
      _windowObj = panel_window;
      _windowObj.document.getElementById("show_count").innerHTML = view_counts;
    });
  }
);

chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(
  function(entries) {
    if(entries.request.url == "http://example.com/"){
      view_counts++;
    }
    _windowObj.document.getElementById("show_count").innerHTML = view_counts;
  }
);
```

Comment: Please explain what was the problem and how your code solves it.

Answer (score 0):

okey, i just try it.

1. hold global the panel_window object.
2. request data write to panel_window's hidden fields when onRequestfinished.
3. panels_window analytics some data on interval events.

---

I hope that perhaps there is smart way.